# SQL syntax identifier issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a SQL assignment to create/update a database and tables. I am getting errors stating "Identifier is not valid input at this position" and "Unexpected identifier". Here is my SQL:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS SparkleDiamonds;    
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE SparkleDiamonds;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Customer;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Customer (
    cust_num INT NOT NULL,
    cust_fname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,  
    cust_lname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_address VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_address2 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_address3 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_Phone_No VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    location2_address VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    location2_address2 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    location2_address3 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_num))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Orders;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Orders (
    order_num INT NOT NULL, 
    cust_num INT NULL,
    order_tran_id INT NULL,
    order_emp_id INT NULL,
    order_transaction_time VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    order_location VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_num))
  *INDEX fk_Orders_Customer_idx (cust_num ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Customer
    FOREIGN KEY cust_num
    REFERENCES SparkleDiamonds.Customer cust_num
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Inventory;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Inventory (
    inv_diam_item_num VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    order_tran_id INT NULL,
    inv_diam_cost DOUBLE NULL,
    inv_diam_price DOUBLE NULL,
    inv_diam_carat DOUBLE NULL,
    inv_diam_clarity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    inv_diam_cut VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    inv_diam_color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    inv_diam_on_hand  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (inv_diam_item_num))
  *INDEX fk_Inventory_Orders_idx (order_tran_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Inventory_Orders1
    FOREIGN KEY (order_tran_id)
    REFERENCES SparkleDiamonds.Inventory (order_tran_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I have put an asterisk where the issues are, the index statements. I am newer to SQL and am unsure what is wrong and what the code should read at these points. What is my issue? What should it read? What code will fix this problem?

Comment: Remove statements one at a time until you isolate where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have syntax errors in this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Orders (
    order_num INT NOT NULL, 
    cust_num INT NULL,
    order_tran_id INT NULL,
    order_emp_id INT NULL,
    order_transaction_time VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    order_location VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_num) )
  *INDEX fk_Orders_Customer_idx (cust_num ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Customer
        FOREIGN KEY cust_num
        REFERENCES SparkleDiamonds.Customer cust_num
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I think you intend:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SparkleDiamonds.Orders (
    order_num INT NOT NULL, 
    cust_num INT NULL,
    order_tran_id INT NULL,
    order_emp_id INT NULL,
    order_transaction_time VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    order_location VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_num),
    INDEX fk_Orders_Customer_idx (cust_num ASC),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Customer
        FOREIGN KEY (cust_num)
        REFERENCES SparkleDiamonds.Customer(cust_num)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Changes:

- Extra paren after `primary key`
- Comma after `primary key` declaration
- Superfluous `*`
- Parentheses around `cust_num` for foreign key constraint

You have similar errors in other tables. You may have other problems.

Comment: I put the asterisk in so where the error is could be spotted

Comment: I am now getting this error: ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 49: Cannot add foreign key constraint